# Is there a way to mimic a HorizontalDragGesture in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When user clicks on a button, I'd like the button to send a swipe right event, so that it triggers a tab switch to a different page. Is there a way to do it without `TabController` or `Navigator` or `PageView`

Basically, I have a `TabController` that navigates between pages but I also want to add the above functionality where user can trigger a tab change **from a completely separate non-tab widget**

EG:

```
TabController:
-page1
-page2
-page3

A different widget page:
-button (click to trigger a switch to page2 above)
```

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Connect a service'),
      onTap: () => send HorizontalDragGesture event,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: " so that it triggers a tab switch to a different page. Is there a way to do it without TabController or Navigator" So what do you actually want to do? There is the [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) widget.

Comment: You can pass the controller to it's children and manipulate it from there or pass down methods that allow you to do that.

Comment: I think I know what you're suggesting. The problem is the trigger widget page is not one of the tab controller pages. So in this case, I'd have to pass the controller to a different widget which I think it could be done through stream?! but that seems too complicated.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your application, but there should be a way to pass down the method you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

```
PageView(
  controller: _pageController,
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Page 1'),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _pageController.nextPage(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut
            );
          },
          child: Text('Go to Page 2'),
        )
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Page 2'),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _pageController.previousPage(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut
            );
          },
          child: Text('Go to Page 1'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added more details to the question. In my case, the page view won't help unfortunately.